# Errors in Compile

Tags: compile

I defined a function

```
getCell[sp_, i_, j_, x_] := Block[{target, n, m, k, l, k2, l2, cells},
  n = Dimensions[sp][[1]];
  m = Dimensions[sp][[2]];
  cells = {};
  Do[
   Do[
    (* This is one neighbor *)
    k2 = Mod[i + k, n, 1];
    l2 = Mod[j + l, m, 1];
    If[(k2 != i || l2 != j) && sp[[k2, l2]] == x, 
     AppendTo[cells, {k2, l2}]],
    {l, -1, 1}],
   {k, -1, 1}];
  If[Dimensions[cells][[1]] != 0,
   target = RandomSample[cells, 1][[1]],
   (* The default, if none was found, is to return the cell itself, 
   just for convenience *)
   target = {i, j}
   ];
  Return[target];
  ]
```

`getCell` given a square matrix `sp` filled with Integers attempts to find a cell neighboring `[[i,j]]` that contains a value equal to `x`. If it finds such a cell, it returns the coordinates of that cell; if not, it returns the input coordinates `{i,j}`.

I now wanted to compile `getCell` to try to speed it up, but when I do so by putting `Compile` around the function and inserting type definitions, I get several error messages:

```
Compile::cset: Variable cells of type {_Integer,1} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,2}. >>

Compile::cpts: The result after evaluating Insert[cells,{k2,l2},-1] should be a tensor. Nontensor lists are not supported at present; evaluation will proceed with the uncompiled function. >>

Compile::cset: Variable target of type {_Integer,2} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,0}. >>

Compile::cset: Variable target of type {_Integer,2} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,1}. >>
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, and how I could get this simple function compiled?

Comment: What code are you feeding to `Compile`?

Comment: Tom, you substantially changed the question after it was answered: please don't do that! Feel free to follow up with a new question *in a new thread*.  Consult our [faq] for more guidance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note: instead of picking random element I just pick the first it runs into, random version at the end

```
getCell = 
 Compile[{{sp, _Integer, 2}, {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {x, _Integer}}, 
  Block[{ n, m, k2, l2, cell},

   {n, m} = Dimensions[sp];
   cell = {i, j};
   Do[(*This is the neighborhood *)
    k2 = Mod[i + k, n, 1];
    l2 = Mod[j + l, m, 1];
    If[(k2 != i || l2 != j) && sp[[k2, l2]] == x, cell = {k2, l2}; 
     Break[]]
    , {l, -1, 1}, {k, -1, 1}];
   cell
   ]]
```

When you get that type of errors about tensor sizes not matching think about what shapes your data has and if Mathematica knows about it. If it's not an argument that you need to specify shape of you can do that by putting the specification as the last `Compile` argument, see the docs for details.

Often the easiest is to explicitly assign the variable a value(see below)

What I changed:

- Explicitly added `{sp,_Integer,2}` so Mathematica knows what it is. This is the one that matters.
- Merged the `Do` loops into one
- Removed `k` and `l` from `Block` variables since `Do` localizes them automatically
- Assigned `{m,n}` simultaneously
- There is no need to explicitly state `Return` what the last function returned gets returned (unless it is suppressed with a `;` in which case it gives `Null`

An example, finding neighboring `0`:

```
m = 5;
r = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {m, m}];
pos = RandomInteger[{1, m}, 2];
cell = getCell[r, pos[[1]], pos[[2]], 0];

s = Grid[r, 
  ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {pos -> Red, cell -> Blue}}]
```

[image: Output grid]

To actually get a random one you can make sure that `cells` is treated correctly by initializing as a nx2 value:

```
getCell = 
 Compile[{{sp, _Integer, 2}, {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {x, _Integer}}, 
  Block[{n, m, k2, l2, cells},

   {n, m} = Dimensions[sp];

   cells = {{i, j}};

   Do[(*This is the neighborhood *)
    k2 = Mod[i + k, n, 1];
    l2 = Mod[j + l, m, 1];
    If[(k2 != i || l2 != j) && sp[[k2, l2]] == x, 
     AppendTo[cells, {k2, l2}]]
    , {l, -1, 1}, {k, -1, 1}];

   If[Length[cells] == 1, {i, j}, RandomChoice[Rest[cells]]]
   ]]
```

Here I do that by just starting with `{i,j}` in it and appending the positions it finds, at the end I pick randomly out of everything but the first value.

Since you are compiling it in the first place I guess you will be running the function a lot and want speed, there are some easy ways to get a nice speedup, the first is compiling to C and the second is to make the function listable.

Say for a given matrix you want to find the nearest 0 neighbor for a list of positions.

```
getCellListableC = 
  Compile[{{sp, _Integer, 2}, {pos, _Integer, 1}, {x, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{n, m, k2, l2, cells, i, j},

    {n, m} = Dimensions[sp];
    {i, j} = pos;
    cells = {{i, j}};

    Do[(*This is the neighborhood *)
     k2 = Mod[i + k, n, 1];
     l2 = Mod[j + l, m, 1];
     If[(k2 != i || l2 != j) && sp[[k2, l2]] == x, 
      AppendTo[cells, {k2, l2}]]
     , {l, -1, 1}, {k, -1, 1}];

    If[Length[cells] == 1, {i, j}, RandomChoice[Rest[cells]]]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable];

m = 5000;
n = 1000;
r = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, {m, m}];
pos = RandomInteger[{1, m}, {n, 2}];

(* Functions i compare to are as the ones above with different Compile options *)
(* Compiled, but not CompilationTarget->"C" *)
AbsoluteTiming[getCell[r, #[[1]], #[[2]], 0] & /@ r;]
(* {0.085699, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[getCellC[r, #[[1]], #[[2]], 0] & /@ r;]
(* {0.077503, Null} *)

(* Take advantage of Listability *)
AbsoluteTiming[getCellListable[r, pos, 0];]
(* {0.008890, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[getCellListableC[r, pos, 0];]
(* {0.004517, Null} *)
```

Note especially how `Listable` improves speed.

Another thing is to always look at after compiling is:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[getCellListableC]
```

If you see `MainEvaluate` that means that part isn't compiled, and figure out how to avoid that. Another thing is `CopyTensor` wherever that occurs a list is copied, you will see that in this code due to the `Append` (among others).

Comment: Thanks so much for this! That's great! I'm new to Compiling functions, so sorry for asking this probably rather trivial question...

Comment: @TomWenseleers I find that making sure Mathematica knows the shape of all variables can be quite non-trivial, but usually worth it to get a factor 10-100 faster code :)

Comment: @TomWenseleers I added a few other things that I think is good to know about when getting started with `Compile`

Comment: Good answer (+1), but just thought I ought to point out that ``Internal`Bag`` is highly preferable to `AppendTo` whenever the $O(n^2)$ behaviour of the latter might represent a performance issue.

Comment: Ha that's really great - that's already quite a speed increase! But indeed very tricky to properly tell Mathematica what variable types you are using.